# Use an SD Card for your Page File - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, pagefile, sd-card

I am using Windows 7 RC and wanted to know if it was possible to use an SD card ( I have a slot for it in my laptop) to hold the page file.

When I try to change my virtual memory settings, it doesn't list the drive as available to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SD card would be classed as a removable device, which would explain why it's not usable to hold the page file (removing the SD would mean a bunch of memory space just disappeared from underneath the kernel -- and (most*) kernels generally don't like that much).

You might get some use out of the SD card as a [ReadyBoost device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost), assuming you can convince Windows to use it.

---

Sidenote: I'm aware some kernels can cope with memory disappearing -- they usually need to be told the memory is going to go first.

Answer (score 0):

You can not page to a drive that Windows considers removable, which includes anything you plug into a USB port or card reader.

Comment: I am sure windows could be commanded to ignore the face device is removable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the exact same thing.
try this neat little site.
http://www.getusb.info/usb-hack-turn-a-usb-stick-into-a-hard-drive-or-local-disk/
it works in that you will now see the SD card as a disk. 
now the last hurdle........ moving the pagefile.
 it keeps coming back to c drive....